# Running flask into the go server

Tags: python, go, flask

I am running go server as my main script. But I have implemented new service in flask. So, presently I have to run flask and go, both server running to see the application UI.

But I want to run only go server. How can I do that? what to integrate flask with go.

Comment: Write a 2 line bash script to start them both together? It's not clear what you are asking. You need to start flask somehow if it's part of your system.